# Adding Authorization Header to HTTP POST request in android(Using JSON)

Tags: android, json, header

My authorization header is "Authorization: TRUEREST username=user &password=pass&apikey=key&class=class". How to put it into HTTPPOST request..?
I am doing it like :

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization","TRUEREST");  
            httppost.setHeader("username","user");
            httppost.setHeader("password","pass");
            httppost.setHeader("apikey","key");
            httppost.setHeader("class","class");
```

Credentials don't get send. What is wrong in this code??
Kindly help..!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();?

Comment: the idea of post is to pass the data in the body and not in the header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, are you sure you need to put all of those in the 'Authorization' header? Second what you are doing is adding 5 different headers with each value, not adding a single 'Authorization' header.

The '&' usually means you need to send those values as POST/GET parameters, but do check your specs.

Comment: heavy thanks fro the reply..!!
Yes I want to put all these in authorization header. 
Okay, then how to add a single authorization header..?(Exact code would be a great help). My Header is "Authorization: TRUEREST username=user &password=pass&apikey=key&class=class".

Comment: Just call  `httppost.setHeader("Authorization", headerValue);` In your case `headerValue` should be "TRUETEST username=...".